# Authentication error with SVN in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I started a project where I have to use an external svn (I'm under a proxy). When I put the url in the configuration project, Jenkins can't access to the repository, so I filled credential (repository url, username and password) but here is the error :

```
FAILED: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /.../trunk/www failed

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /.../trunk/www failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:304)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:289)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:277)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:696)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:619)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1968)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1913)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
        at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /.../trunk/www failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/.../trunk/www'
svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:681)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/.../trunk/www'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:679)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:424)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.connect(SVNSocketFactory.java:112)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:85)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:195)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:360)
        ... 80 more
```

In C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\server, the proxy is configured and in Jenkins, I can install/update plugins.

The svn url is in https and I can access it with credential in a browser.

By default, the svn version used in Jenkins is 1.4, even with the 1.7, impossible to acces to this svn server.

The server is a Windows 7 64-bits and this is the last version of Jenkins.

Where is the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: 'Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect' suggests a network related problem; can you access the external SVN from the network where the Jenkins is deployed?

Comment: Through the browser, I can access to the svn server with the same credentials as in Jenkins. So I don't really understand because the proxy is configured for Subversion.

Comment: Recently I faced this problem: a proxy let my browser executable exit to browse SVN repo in HTTP(S), but did not let my svn executable to do the same. Maybe this is appliable to your issue too...

Comment: Have you tried to execute svn from the command prompt with "--non-interactive --trust-server-cert" on the machine that runs jenkins, to accept certificates permanently?

Comment: Are the Jenkins and SVN servers both on the same network behind the proxy?

Comment: I'm going to add an answer I submitted in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/620459/jenkins-and-https-cannot-connect-to-server/764725#764725) that worked very well.

Answer (score 3):

Really late in the game here, but I just had the same problem. If you run SVN manually on a Jenkins machine, it will create an svn authentication file for your svn server (authentication caching). The existence of that file breaks Jenkins svn.

On my server (windows), the file is located in:

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple
```

I believe on linux, it would be in ~/.subversion

I renamed the directory svn.simple to svn.simple1 and things instantly started working (and broke again when I changed it back).

To prevent this when running the svn bin on the Jenkins server, you can

- update your %APPDATA%\Subversion\config file by uncommenting "store-passwords = no"
- or use this flag: --no-auth-cache

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `${user.home}/.subversion`.

Comment: Which user home, on the Jenkins server, jenkins slave, subversion server?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command with this option:

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to submit an answer I submitted on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/620459/jenkins-and-https-cannot-connect-to-server/764725#764725) that worked really well for me. The solution was to edit the Jenkins.xml file directly at its `<arguments>` element to include

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.myproxy.com Dhttp.proxyPort=99999 -Dhttp.auth.preference=Basic
```

Apparently this allows the Java internals to pass through the proxy server.