# Authentification error with SVN in Jenkins 4

Tags: jenkins, svn, continuous-integration, svn-checkout

**Can any one tell me how to fix svn (subvirsion) integrate with jenkins CI,**
i am giving this svn url: https://svn.digitalmettle.com:8443/svn/src/Vantage/VIP.Touch/trunk
but jenkins subvirsion give this error:

> Unable to access
>   https://svn.digitalmettle.com:8443/svn/src/Vantage/VIP.Touch/trunk :
>   svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/src/Vantage/VIP.Touch/trunk failed (show
>   details) (Maybe you need to enter credential?)

**i also check these answers but not work:**

1. [Jenkins not able to use SVN credentials or download new plugins/new versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625614/jenkins-not-able-to-use-svn-credentials-or-download-new-plugins-new-versions)
2. [Authentication error with SVN in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527800/authentification-error-with-svn-in-jenkins)

Comment: does it need user id/password? full stack trace ?

Comment: yes but when i give user name and password it gives this error.
Error

FAILED: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/src/Vantage/VIP.Touch/trunk failed

Answer (score 1):

Well, just clicking on your URL in a browser brings up the error message that SSL certificate is not trusted. You are probably using a self-signed certificate.

The SVN plugin must be getting back the same error message, and it doesn't know how to react to it.

Fix your SSL, and it will work